# Windows 7 - VPN and host name lookup

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, vpn, windows-7, netbios

I have set up a VPN server using a Sinology box for accessing my office network from home.

I can access all the office IPs, but the host name resolution has some problems. DNS queries work : nslookup commands are successful. However, if I enter an office-local hostname in any software (including ping) it fails resolving the IP address. But if I add a dot to the hostname, it works.

So it seems that:

- DNS on local hostnames works perfectly. The internet router is the DNS server in that case.
- Windows apps use DNS queries for resolving names which contain a dot (which can be domain qualified hostnames, or just a local hostname with a dot appended)
- Windows apps use other mechanisms (NetBIOS? WINS?) for resolving plain hostnames without any dot.
- VPN is not working with these other mechanisms.

Is there any way to get name lookup working? For example by forcing windows to use DNS and no other mechanism on this connection?

I cannot use fixed IPs and hosts files as there are often changes in the connected computers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Synology VPN but usually (eg.ppp,l2ipsec,openvpn,etc.)   when the vpn starting, the remote system provide you a remote WINS/DNS server  or/and the suffix name in order to search the hosts in the DNS without domain (it depends how is configured)

So please take a look when your VPN start if the system gives you the DNS search suffix (eg: example.com) otherwise add by hand.
I hope it helps!.

Comment: I have no Active Directory or domain, this is a simple network. The machines I'm trying to reach are not on a domain!

Comment: anyway add the dns search suffix to your pc